# mb_internal_encoding() not available though configured?

Tags: php, mbstring

I'm having problem with mbstring in my Apache2.2/Win7/PHP5.3 setup, though I think it's correctly configured in my php.ini:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

I get the following:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_internal_encoding() in ...
```

I did a manual installation (by the book) using the VC6 .zip. I'm running out of ideas of what to try.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are using the right `php.ini`? Can you confirm using `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Yes (only one on my system), and I just checked it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, crap! PHP didn't understand the relative path. Perhaps that had something to do with me doing a manual installation...

Solution in php.ini:

```
extension_dir = "c:\RnD\PHP\ext"
```